Creating Poly Service URL with location validation
I am new to mapping and trying to create a Geocoding Service URL and a Poly Service URL for address verification. The Poly Service URL has been an issue trying to input a polygon to verify locations entered by individuals are within the boundaries before submitting info.
Do you have any tips to create one with 2 cities in the boundaries?
So far I can get part of it to verify through a map server, but not the entire thing, a feature server will not work for verification for some reason.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are getting at here, but it sounds like you just need to publish the polygon feature service to AGOL. You could then use whatever flavor of geocoding service you prefer to handle an address into coordinates and then query an intersect on the service, in which it will return JSON with any features the coordinates intersect. Does this sound like what you are wanting to do?
